# How to run ShinyApp standalone?

Tags: r, shiny

I red a lot of answers to this question, but I really confused.
I've a ShinyApp, and I want to run it by click on some icon in my desktop, without using R or command line.
I dont want to upload the app to the server, only in my computer.
what is the best way to do it?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Rshiny+electron+app&atb=v286-1&ia=web, https://chasemc.github.io/electricShine/,
https://github.com/dirkschumacher/r-shiny-electron/, 
https://foretodata.com/how-to-make-a-standalone-desktop-application-with-shiny-and-electron-on-windows/

Comment: maybe a two-lined ``.bat`` that publishes the shiny app through ``R CMD``, and calls chrome.exe/whatever that opens it? Unless this is what you mean by not using the command line.